# Error when building BasicDecoder with GreedyEmbeddingHelper

Tags: python, tensorflow, encoder-decoder

I'm trying to build a basic encoder-decoder model. I build the model for training graph and it works perfect. The helper of the decoder is `tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper` . But when I switch to helper to `tf.contrib.seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingHelper` it throws a shape error.

Here it is my working helper.

```
helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper(
decoder_emb_inp, decoder_lengths, time_major=True)
```

And here it is the what I want to do.

```
start_tokens = tf.fill([batch_size], vezins_dict[start_token_str])
    end_token = vezins_dict[end_token_str]

helper = tf.contrib.seq2seq.GreedyEmbeddingHelper(decoder_emb_inp, 
    start_tokens, end_token)
```

I am using the same decoder and dynamic_decoding. It works with `TrainingHelper`, but it didn't work with `GreedyEmbeddingHelper`.

```
# decoder   
decoder = tf.contrib.seq2seq.BasicDecoder(
    decoder_cell, helper, encoder_state, 
    output_layer=projection_layer)

# Dynamic decoding
outputs, _, _ = tf.contrib.seq2seq.dynamic_decode(decoder)
logits = outputs.rnn_output
```

And here it is the error.

```
ValueError: linear is expecting 2D arguments: 
  [TensorShape([Dimension(20), Dimension(20), Dimension(10)]), 
  TensorShape([Dimension(20), Dimension(128)])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on `GreedyEmbeddingHelper`s input. When using *Greedy Helper*, no needs for decoder input.

This is wrong embedding input for *Greedy Helper*

```
embedding_decoder = tf.get_variable(
        "embedding_decoder", [out_alphabet_size, embedding_size])
decoder_emb_inp = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(
        embedding_decoder, decoder_inputs)
```

It needs to be like this for *Greedy*

```
decoder_emb_inp = tf.get_variable(
        "embedding_decoder", [out_alphabet_size, embedding_size])
```